# Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 4.1.1, failed version requirement: >=5.0.0-dev

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, command-line-interface

I have a problem with cordova CLI, when I try to add a plugin which is in the NPM list of published plugins I get this error:

"Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-         android: 4.1.1, failed version requirement: >=5.0.0-dev"

I saw this problem in stackoverflow here:[Cordova-plugin-camera is not being loaded; failed version requirement for cordova-android version: >5.0.0-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313112/cordova-plugin-camera-is-not-being-loaded-failed-version-requirement-for-cordov)

But this was due to using the version in Github and the recommended solution was to use the version published in npm via the Cordova CLI which is what I have been doing.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What cordova android version are you using in cordova?  Have you deleted, upgraded and readded the android platform component as your project may still be using the old version if you haven't done this step.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem, turns out cordova released a new stable version for Android November 9th. I just had to updated via:

```
    $cordova platform update android@5.0.0
```

Comment: How to check current cordova-android version?

Comment: Also we have to add back plugin like
cordova plugin add plugin.name

Then perfect..

Comment: @wmfairuz use `cordova platforms` to list version of currently installed platforms.

Comment: How do you fix this within phonegap build?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem with this command:

> cordova platform update android

**Note:** After that remove your android platform(cordova platform remove android) and add once again android platform(cordova platform add android)