# How to update Platform in (MDHA) MultiDeviceHybridApp

Tags: cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am trying to use Camera plugin in a Crodva app developing by (MultiDeviceHybridApp) and I get this error:

> Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 4.1.1, failed version requirement: >=5.0.0-dev
>
> Skipping 'cordova-plugin-camera' for android

based on the answer of this post [Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 4.1.1, failed version requirement: >=5.0.0-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921935/plugin-doesnt-support-this-projects-cordova-android-version-cordova-android) it seems that I need to upgrade the Platform, but running the below command in project folder will show this error

```
cordova platform update android@5.0.0
```

> Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and I am writing it in case some body else has the same problem

Open this folder `%AppData%\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\platforms` there are two files in there,

open `platformsConfig.json` 
You can see different platforms there, find `android` and change

```
"android": {
    "parser_file": "../cordova/metadata/android_parser",
    "handler_file": "../plugman/platforms/android",
    "url": "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git",
    "version": "~4.1.0"
},
```

to

```
"android": {
    "parser_file": "../cordova/metadata/android_parser",
    "handler_file": "../plugman/platforms/android",
    "url": "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git",
    "version": "~5.0.0"
},
```

`Clean` your project and build it again. ;)